# Java - узнать разрядность ОС Windows средствами Java

Tags: java

Дело в том, что в моем приложении в зависимости от разрядности ОС нужно вызывать разные методы. Собственно, возник вопрос: как я с помощью java-кода могу узнать разрядность ОС?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109679/how-to-check-windows-edition-in-java) предлагают запустить systeminfo и посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот кусок кода из рабочего приложения:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase();
String swtFileName = 
    osName.contains("win") ? "win" :
    osName.contains("mac") ? "macosx" :
//        osName.contains("linux") || osName.contains("nix") ? "linux_gtk" : 
// Linux version is to come yet
    null;     

if (swtFileName == null)
  throw new RuntimeException("Unknown OS name: "+osName);

swtFileName += osArch.contains("64") ? "64" : "32";
swtVersion = swtFileName;
swtFileName = "swt_" + swtFileName + ".jar";
```

Answer (score 2):

Версию операционной системы, можно получить через [список системных свойств](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
String version = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```